# Wavelet for time series

Tags: python, quantitative-finance, wavelet, pywavelets

I am trying to use wavelets coefficients as feature for neural networks on a time series data and I am bit confused on usage of the same. Do I need to find the coefficients on entire time series at once, or use a sliding window for finding the same. I mean, will finding coefficients on entire time series for once, include the future data points while determining those coefficients? What should be the approach to go about using Wavelets on a time series data without look ahead bias if any?

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to provide you with a detailed answer without knowing what you are trying to achieve.

In a nutshell, you first need to decide whether you want to apply a **discrete** (DWT) or a **continous** (CWT) wavelet transform to your time series.

A DWT will allow you to decompose your input data into a set of discrete levels, providing you with information about the frequency content of the signal *i.e.* determining whether the signal contains high frequency variations or low frequency trends. Think of it as applying several band-pass filters to your input data.

I do not think that you should apply a DWT to your entire time series at once. Since you are working with financial data, maybe decomposing your input signal into 1-day windows and applying a DWT on these subsets would do the trick for you.

In any case, I would suggest:

- Installing the `pywt` toolbox and playing with a dummy time series to understand how wavelet decomposition works.
- Checking out the abundant literature available about wavelet analysis of financial data. For instance, if you are interested into financial time series forecasting, you might want to read [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.07278.pdf).
- Posting your future questions on the [DSP stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), unless you have a specific coding-related answer.